# how to use getPublicEncryptionKey from eth-sig-util in a Dapp

Tags: metamask

The metamask repo includes  small collection of ethereum signing functions:
https://github.com/MetaMask/eth-sig-util

There is a function (not exposed in readme section) named getEncryptionPublicKey which expects a private key. How is this supposed to be used, as we can never get a private key in our dapp.
This functionality is based on that: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/1098
I would like to use this functionality.